# Create formatted text output based on partial string finding

Tags: data-visualization, patternmatching

I am wondering which software I should use to accomplish the following:

I have a list of partial sequences:

```
EZEO   
HDZEZWI   
SVBWG   
ZSZS   
KCOEOIUI   
OIUIUPPEGB
```

And a list of full sequences:

```
HSVSGEZEODPDNCHDZEZWIQSNCD
GHSVBWGTDIEODMDBVAHWZSZSHS
TZUEUZDFNKCOEOIUIUPPEGBOPOJD
```

Now I want to find all the partial sequences in all of the full sequences (the partial sequences might even overlap) and create an output which looks like this:

```
1. HSVSG**EZEO**DPDNC**HDZEZWI**QSNCD  
2. GH**SVBWG**TDIEODMDBVAHW**ZSZS**HS 
3. TZUEUZDFN**KCOEOIUIUPPEGB**OPOJD
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And we are wondering what OS it should run on, how much it may cost when it comes to paid software, and if there are any license considerations. Can you tell us? :)

Comment: I wonder what has higher priorities: finding  short sequences or longer sequences? What is the minimum length? 4 as in 'EZEO' is rather short. What should happen if 2 searchstrings match, e.g. EZEO and ZZEZEOZZ ? ....

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -E`.

If your partial strings are in a fiel called `partial` and your sequences in `sequences`, then:

```
pattern=""
for line in $(cat partial); do
  pattern="$pattern($line)|"
done

pattern=$(echo ${pattern%?})

grep -E --color $pattern sequences
```

The loop builds the command

```
grep -n -E --color '(EZEO)|(HDZEZWI)|(SVBWG)|(ZSZS)|(KCOEOIUI)|(OIUIUPPEGB)' sequences
```

Elsewhere there are suggestions à la

```
grep -f partial sequences
```

but that didn't work for me.